# Counting the number of lines that have the same entry in the first column in bash

Tags: bash, perl, shell, stata

I have a data file that looks like the following:

```
123456, 1623326
123456, 2346525
123457, 2435466
123458, 2564252
123456, 2435145
```

The first column is the "ID" -- a string variable. The second column does not matter to me. I want to end up with

```
123456, 3
123457, 1
123458, 1
```

where the second column now counts how many entries there are in the original file that correspond with the unique "ID" in the first column.

Any solution in bash or perl would be fantastic. Even Stata would be good, but I figure this is harder to do in Stata. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I once read when you offer _two_ shrimps to a sea horse for food, they will die of starvation because they cannot decide which one to pick. Seems you're in similar trouble right now ;-)

Comment: @PerlDog... there's some quality answers for a nice array of different methods :)

Comment: @stevieb Right you are. I like one best because I learned sth. new (but I won't tell which one, not to influence the sea horse). But we're lacking a _stata_ solution (whatever that is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cut -d',' -f1 in.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 ", " $1}'
```

gives:

```
123456, 3
123457, 1
123458, 1
```

Comment: Ended up choosing this one haha! Thanks so much. the other STATA answer was great as well. Can't believe I didn't know about that command...

Answer (score 6):

In Stata this is just

```
contract ID
```

Comment: I can't stop laughing. Is that really true? Wow! Looks like someone wanted to post a MySQL question but hit the submit button prematurely. Cool.

Answer (score 3):

Split off the number in the first field and use it as a hash key, increasing its count each time

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'data_cnt.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my %cnt;
while (<$fh>) {
    $cnt{(/^(\d+)/)[0]}++;
}

print "$_, $cnt{$_}\n" for keys %cnt;
```

The regex captures consecutive digits at a beginning of a line. As that is returned as a list we index into it to get the number, `(/.../)[0]`, which is used as a hash key.  When a number is seen for the first time it is added to the hash as a key and its value is set to 1 due to `++`. When a number that already exists as a key is seen its value is incremented by `++`. This is a typical frequency counter.

With your numbers in file `data_cnt.txt` this outputs

```
123457, 1
123456, 3
123458, 1
```

The output can be sorted by hash values, if you need that

```
say "$_, $cnt{$_}" for sort { $cnt{$b} <=> $cnt{$a} } (keys %cnt);
```

Prints

```
123456, 3
123457, 1
123458, 1
```

---

This can fit into a one-liner, if preferred for some reason

```
perl -nE '
    $cnt{(/^(\d+)/)[0]}++; 
    }{ say "$_, $cnt{$_}" for sort { $cnt{$b} <=> $cnt{$a} } keys %cnt
' data_cnt.txt
```

It should be entered as one line at a terminal. The `}{` is short for the `END { }` block. The code is the same from the short script above. The `-E` is the same as `-e` while it enables feature `say`.

Answer (score 3):

This counts the number of lines with the same first six characters:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c -w6
      3 123456, 1623326
      1 123457, 2435466
      1 123458, 2564252
```

#### Documentation

From `man uniq`:

> **-w, --check-chars=N**
>   compare no more than N characters in lines

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} counts[$1]++{} END{for (i in counts) print i, counts[i]}' file

123456, 3
123457, 1
123458, 1
```

- `FS=OFS=", "` Sets input & output field separator as `", "`
- `counts[$1]++{}` increments a counter stored by first column in array `counts` by `1` for every instance. `{}` is same do-nothing
- In the `END` block we iterate through `counts` array and print each unique `id` and the `count`

Answer (score 2):

`cut`, `sort`, `uniq`, `sed` version

```
cut -d',' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\2, \1/'
```

or simple Perl version with sorted by the first column

```
perl -F',' -anE'$s{$F[0]}++}{say"$_, $s{$_}"for sort keys%s'
```

or sorted by count descending and then by the first column

```
perl -F',' -anE'$s{$F[0]}++}{say"$_, $s{$_}"for sort{$s{$b}<=>$s{$a}or$a cmp$b}keys%s'
```

or in order in which key comes first

```
perl -F',' -anE'push@a,$F[0]if!$s{$F[0]}++}{say"$_, $s{$_}"for@a'
```

or just in pseudorandom order

```
perl -F',' -anE'$s{$F[0]}++}{say"$_, $s{$_}"for keys%s'
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -naE '$h{$F[0]}++}{for(sort keys %h){say "$_ $h{$_}"}' file.txt

123456, 3
123457, 1
123458, 1
```

`-n` loops over each line in the file

`-a` splits each line on whitespace, and populates `@F` array with each entry

`}{` denotes an `END` block, which allows us to iterate over the hash after all lines in the file have been processed

Answer (score 0):

In Perl

```
$ perl -MData::Dump -ne "++@n{/(\d+)/}; END {dd \%n}" data.txt
{ 123456 => 3, 123457 => 1, 123458 => 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

With [datamash](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

```
datamash -W -s -g1 count 1 < data
```

Output:

```
123456, 3
123457, 1
123458, 1
```